# How to use a variable within a class that will be independent of any objects created in python?

Tags: python, class, variables

I want to use a variable that will be independent of any objects the class may have :

```
    class A:
        var = 5
    ob1 = A()
    ob2 = A()
    ob1.var += 2
    print ob2.var
```

I want that once ob1 modifies the value of var from 5 to 7, ob2.var also shows up 7 instead of 5. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `ob1.var += 2` you are not modifying the class attribute, you are creating a new instance variable with the same name as the class attribute.  For example:

```
>>> ob1 = A()
>>> ob1.var += 2
>>> ob1.__dict__
{'var': 7}
>>> ob1.__class__.__dict__
{'var': 5, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
```

If you want to modify the class attribute, just use `A.var += 2`.  If you need to do this from an instance you can use `ob1.__class__.var += 2`.

Here is how you could implement the behavior you want using properties on a [new-style class](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class):

```
class A(object):
    _var = 5

    @property
    def var(self):
        return self.__class__._var

    @var.setter
    def var(self, value):
        self.__class__._var = value
```

Now with this class when you get or set the `var` variable on an instance of `A`, it will actually be getting or setting a class attribute.  For example:

```
>>> ob1 = A()
>>> ob2 = A()
>>> ob1.var += 2
>>> ob2.var
7
```

Answer (score 2):

you are already close

```
class MyData:
    my_data_var = 4

class A:
    def fun1():
       MyData.my_data_var += 2

    def fun2():
       return MyData.my_data_var

def main():
    print MyData.my_data_var 
    a = A()
    a.fun1()    
    print a.fun2()
    b = A()
    b.fun1()
    print b.fun2()
    print a.fun1()

main()
```

these are static class variables ... there are other ways to simillarly utilize them ... but this was a simple quick example

Comment: Depending on how you want the API to look, you might consider making `fun1` and `fun2` `classmethod`s and attaching `my_data_var` directly to `A`

Comment: yeah  I was gonna but i figured it maybe less confusing to a new pythonista to do it this way ... but tbh I think your solution is the most elegant

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could use a `property` to do something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    _var = 5

    @property
    def var(self):
        return self._var

    @var.setter
    def var(self,value):
        self.__class__._var = value

a = Foo()
b = Foo()

a.var += 3
assert a.var == 8
assert b.var == 8

c = Foo()
assert c.var == 8 #(un-instantiated objects pick up the change as well)

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

bar = Bar()
assert bar.var == 8
a.var += 1

#changes to Foo.var affect Bar until a bar object makes it's own changes
assert bar.var == 9    

# changes to a subclass's property don't have any effect on the parent class
bar.var += 2
assert bar.var == 11
assert a.var == 9
```

As noted in the comments, this could get a little tedious if you have a lot of properties which behave this way.  A slightly more general solution would be to do something like:

```
class ClassAttribute(object):
    def __init__(self,vname,default=None):
        self.vname = '_'+str(vname)
        self.default = default

    def __get__(self,instance,owner):
        return getattr(owner,self.vname,self.default)

    def __set__(self,instance,value):
        setattr(instance.__class__,self.vname,value)

class Foo(object):
    var = ClassAttribute("var",5)

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
a.var += 2
print a.var
print b.var
```

Comment: A property works, but wrapping a class attribute in an instance method so that it behaves like an instance attribute feels wasteful.  A full custom descriptor would mean the setter/getter would exist only once for the class, which seems a more correct way to do it to me.  On the other hand, I could see how the complexity of implementing that could be viewed as unnecessary compared to what you did with decorators.

Comment: @sr2222 -- Added a `ClassAttribute` descriptor.  any thoughts?

Comment: A metaclass?  ;)  I guess there really is no way to make hacking the language seemless, easy, obvious, and pretty at the same time.

Comment: What exactly is @property doing? And of course the same question for @var.setter?

Comment: @IndradhanushGupta -- `@property` makes it so that when you do `print a.var` the `var` function actually gets called.  doing `@var.setter` is the same thing except it specifies the function to be called when you try to set the `var` attribute `a.var = something`